# The herd of cattle had grown to 30 head. Why didn't the writer write 30 heads?

Tags: grammar

Why is "30 head" singular instead of plural in this sentence? Can you explain more about it?

Comment: Extremely related and possibly counting as a duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119843/origins-of-head-as-a-synecdoche

Comment: Please use capital letters and spaces between words in your question. This is an English language site after all.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think it's a duplicate. The duplicate would explain that people also say "five dozen" instead of "five dozens", "four score" instead of "four scores", and used to say "three pair" instead of "three pairs". I think there's a question like that, but I can't find it. [Tangentially related Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+pair%2Cthree+pairs&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthree%20pair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%20pairs%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps it's [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54828/why-is-it-that-score-is-used-in-singular-when-referring-to-several-groups-of-20) then. But *head* refers to a single animal; using a different word like *unit* doesn't work the same way. Perhaps **this** question is the root question that the other one will be a duplicate of.

Comment: Since "head" is one animal, I'm not even sure I'm right when I classify "head" with these number terms (*brace, dozen, score*) that don't get an 's' in constructions like "three brace of quails".

Comment: “30 head” isn't singular, it's plural.  Perhaps you mean to ask why there's no *s* after  *head*

Comment: My grandmother used to call head of cattle describing each mother but not the calf.. I asked why not the calf she said it’s not considered cattle until it’s over 1-2 years old... she had 200-300 head,with almost as many calves...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Dave
>   Phillips](http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/812-head-or-heads-of-cattle/)
>   says: In BrE we would always say a head of cattle (meaning the whole
>   herd) but we wouldn't give a number of those head/heads.

While I would concede that the usage "X head" is not unknown here, the use of 'head' as a synonym of the collective noun 'herd' *is* probably more common in the UK.

........

Because 'cattle' is a plural noun with no singular (though it almost grades into a mass noun notionally in constructions such as 'raising cattle costs a lot of money' – cf *clothing*, *furniture*, and especially *poultry* – which, however, take singular concord), there is the problem of what to call a single – er, beast. Neat. The very familiar *cow* doesn't always work. Perhaps because of the notional massness of cattle, we don't say 'three cattle' etc either – it doesn't accept all normal quantifiers.

This is probably one reason why the term 'head of cattle' has been drafted into use. 'x head of' is then a compound quantifier usable with 'cattle'; the variant 'a single head of cattle' is also available.

Though this is a strange construction even for a quantifier, other more familiar quantifiers are known to take zero plurals (30 dozen ...).

Comment: 'Ten head of cattle' means a heard of *ten animals*, but 'Ten heads of cattle' would mean *ten (severed) heads*.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you check your dictionary.

For example, the Merriam-Webster dictionary says the plural form for this definition is "head".

head noun meaning #4b
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head

Comment: But note that it's "thirty head of cattle" but "thirty heads of lettuce".

Comment: Maybe you need check in a dictionary too. 30 head of cattle is grammatical. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cattle

Comment: But this metonymic usage in the dictionary link given offers no explanation of why it is never used in the singular (one head of cattle???) and always with an unusual plural form. Which is what OP is asking for.

Comment: @Edwin: If you only have one head of cattle, you can always call it a "cow", a "steer", a "bull", or a "calf".

Comment: @Peter: If YOU want to get that close ... The genderless 'neat' has been used, but doesn't seem very idiomatic.

Answer (score -4):

Both heads and head are correct. It's simply more common to say head. Look up the term Isogloss as it explains this a bit more.

Comment: Why would the term ‘isogloss’ explain this? What does this have to do with isoglosses in any possible way? I for one have never heard of this as any kind of dialectal distinguisher.

Comment: Why do you say "thirty heads of cattle" is grammatical? Do you have a justification for this?

Comment: Thirty head of cattle will have thirty heads. One hopes.